# Please remove the ... when posting a SE network question is comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

Can the `...` be lost from the end of links to this site. Have a look at the comment below.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I think it's unnecessary as the link ID is always shown - the text afterwards is not needed in the link.

Comment: So remove it manually. Why special-case such an insignificant detail?

Comment: @Doorknob Can't remove it manually... It's when you paste in a url like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093/please-remove-the-when-posting-a-se-network-question-is-comments

Comment: Why can't you remove it manually? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093

Comment: @Doorknob I can, what I'm saying is the site removes the text of it, why add the ...?

Comment: Huh? "the site removes the text of it"—what does this mean?

Comment: @Doorknob I paste in this link: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093/please-remove-the-when-posting-a-se-network-question-is-comments` the site turns it to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093/...` I want it to be `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093`

Comment: Yes, so just delete the `/please-remo...` part manually.

Comment: @Doorknob but the site already does... and adds a `...` I'm saying stop adding the `...`.

Comment: No, the site doesn't. It simply truncates the text display, but it does not actually change the target of the link. It does the same thing to every other link, ex. `http://example.com/this/is/a/long/example/link/and/stuff/and/it/is/very/long` → http://example.com/this/is/a/long/example/link/and/stuff/and/it/is/very/long

Comment: You can force the issue by using markdown links `[http://example.com/this/is/a/long/example/link/and/stuff/and/it/is/very/long](http://example.com/this/is/a/long/example/link/and/stuff/and/it/is/very/long)` -> [http://example.com/this/is/a/long/example/link/and/stuff/and/it/is/very/long](http://example.com/this/is/a/long/example/link/and/stuff/and/it/is/very/long).

Comment: @Doorknob I know, it displays internal links down to `site.se.com/questions/id/...` and I want it to display them as `site.se.com/questions/id/` by deafult... What's wrong with that?

Comment: So you can remove the last part of the URL, if three dots bother you that much.

Comment: @Doorknob Yes, yes I know the workaround. I'm not asking for a workaround though.

Comment: It's not a workaround. The behavior displayed here is entirely correct. Back to my original comment: "Why special-case such an insignificant detail?"

Comment: @Doorknob yes, I know it is the correct, designed behaviour. This is a feature request for that reason...? And why? is "because I don't like the current behaviour" good enough?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093

Comment: @Tim - [tag:status-completed]. All it needs is a keyboard, and you can choose what to paste in the comment textbox.

Comment: Seriously now, if we won't show "..." on links we'll have ugly comments with whole lines of unreadable links. Not a pleasant thing.

Comment: @Tim you mention this is unnecessary.  And yes, you are correct.  But you really haven't made a strong case as to why this change is needed.  Does the current design cause a problem or otherwise make the site difficult to use?  Or is this just a personal aesthetic concern

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did say to the site - not any link, just internal ones.

Comment: @psubsee2003 aestetic.

Comment: Well, still way too minor to be worth the dev's time, in my opinion.

Comment: @ShadowWizard well yes perhaps. I'd have thought there'd be a `...` somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

You can always remove the last part of the URL, if three dots bother you that much.

I don't see why it's necessary to special-case such an insignificant detail. There's nothing wrong with the current behavior.

Comment: But there is no need for those `...` - there is no extra info gained from them and you already have the id. It's not like it could be cut in the middle of a word.

Comment: @Tim I'm kind of neutral on this request. But I'd just like to add that websites generally use ellipses to tell a user reading it that there it something more to that link. Now, whether that should still happen if the link is *clickable* is a different matter, hence the neutrality :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yeah, as it's clickable - plus the text that it's hidden is completely unnecessary to the link - `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093/please-remove-the-when-posting-a‌​-se-network-question-is-comments` goes to the same place as `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093`

Answer (score 3):

This would be a harmful feature if implemented, because it would present the URL as something different from what it is. When I see

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093/`

I expect that this is the full URL, which is a link to the question with that ID.

When I see

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093/...`

it is clear that the full URL is not shown. It may be a link to a question. It may be a link to an answer under that question, like

`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093/please-remove-the-when-posting-a-se-network-question-is-comments/257097#257097`

Or it may be a link to a comment under an answer under that question. The dots tell me that if I want to know what the link is, I should hover over it to get the full URL.

Comment: Well leave it alone for the comments etc then? But why have `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093/...` when it links to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257093/name`?

Comment: It's a simple general principle: if a string is too long to be shown to the user in full, you put ... or some other visual indication of this fact. Any string, anywhere.

Comment: Okay, rephrase. Why doesn't se auto remove the text that isn't needed?

Comment: Yes, SE should auto-remove this feature request; I think it's not needed.

Comment: unfortunate, SE allows people to add a request even if others disagree.